# How to change ComboBox.Text on a hidden panel?

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

ComboBox1 is on a hidden panel (panelSky)

```
ComboBox1.Text = "323";
panelSky.Visible = true; // combo doesn't have text "323'
```

What is the reason, please?
If panel is visible I can change comboText to "323" regardless "323" is in the item list or not.

Comment: Please check, if "323" is present in the Items of the ComboBox.

Comment: Whether or not it's hidden at the time shouldn't matter. Are you sure that there isn't more code running preventing the UI from updating?

Comment: when panel is visible I can change comboText to "323" regardless "323" is in the item list or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a little test with your scenario. I created a new `winforms` application with a panel and a `combobox`.  On the form load,  I set the panel's visibility to false and set the `combobox` to `"323"` and then I set the visibility of the panel to true and `"323"` was still there.  This is what I did:

```
pnlSky.Visible = false;
comboBox1.Text = "323";
pnlSky.Visible = true;
```

There must be something in your markup or code that is causing an issue when setting the `combobox` value when the `panel` is not visible.  Can you post markup and what code that occurs before and after you set the value of the `combobox`?

Based on your comment to `@HatSoft` about updating the `combobox` from `button` on another `panel`, I ran the following code and it still updated the hidden `combobox`

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     combobox1.Text = "323";
     pnlSky.Visible = true;
 }
```

Comment: Saied, please place that combo on a hiden panel and a button on another (visible) panel, or on a Form itself.Then try my code.

Comment: @Alegro, I have, the combobox1 is on a hidden panel (pnlSky) and the button1 is on another visible panel (panel1)

Comment: @Alegro, Also are your combobox items bound at runtime or design time?  If runtime, how are you binding them (show code if possible)?

Comment: @Alegro, I know my code is not your code, I am just trying to come up with a similar scenario.  If you post your code, then maybe we can get a better idea of what the problem might be?

Comment: @ Saied, my code is on the starting question. And if panel is visible I can change comboText regardless the way of bounding

Comment: @Alegro, that is just 2 lines.  Can you post some more, such as the whole button click, maybe what happens in form load as well?

Comment: @ Saied, the same "just two lines code" works well if panel is visible. It's not relevant any other code.

Comment: @Alegro, I am sorry if you are frustrated. I think it would just help if you posted some more code.  And I have to disagree, everything works together, so it is all relevant.  If you don't want to post code, then so be it.

Comment: It is elemenatar logic. If code works by visible panels, and doesn't work by invisible panels, what is the purpose of analyzing form.Load etc. that procedure is the same in both cases (visible or invisible panel)

Comment: Here is my logic, I put a combobox on a hidden panel and when I click a button on another panel, the combox value is set, so by elementary logic, the same should work for you, but it is not, therefore, something is happening either before or after the combobox is hidden in your code.

Comment: I can't believe. I tryed this code on an new project, without any onteh code

Comment: @Alegro, that is exactly what I did, I hid the panel at design time, clicked a button on another visible panel to update the combo box and set the hidden panel to visible and the value is in the combobox.

Comment: Give me a minute, please, i will try again on a new project

Comment: @ Saied, you're right. It works if comboitems are in a Collection, but doesn't work if combo is populated via DataSet. Sory, ExcuseMe, MyAppologise.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the Combo Type (ie DropDownStyle) is not appropriate...

Try to use `Combo1.Items.Add("323")` instead, and then set the index to 0 (first item)

```
Combo1.SelectedIndex = 0
```

Comment: when panel is visible I can change comboText to "323" regardless "323" is in the item list or not.

Comment: There must be some Load or Activate event on the Panel that is reinitializing the controls.  This is not normal behavior...Are these static controls?  Have you got any events handled in the Panel ? If so - put some breakpoints and check the Stats of the ComboBox

Comment: You can force the ComboBox to update using ComboBox.Invalidate() and ComboBox.Update()..Then check the Text property in code (Debug.Writeline(ComboBox.Text)) - if the text is set properly and returns 323, then you have some event that is reloading the ComboBox, check all references to it...

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly Combox1 lives in the container of Type Panel

So the below code my do the trick

```
        if (comboBox1.Parent.Visible)
        {
            comboBox1.Text = "323";
        }
```

**Update : After more knowledge on your Scenario**

button1 lives in Panel1 that is visible and combox1 lives in Panel2 that is not visible

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (comboBox1.Parent.Visible)
        {
            comboBox1.Text = "323";
        }
    }
```

Comment: this works, but I want to change comboText on a hidden panel, and then show the panel.

Comment: I see what you mean so the comboBox1.Text must change when skypanel.Visible is false.. But at what or which event will you do the change txt for comboBox1

Comment: @ HatSoft, I want to change comboText on a hiden panel, without "if".